# How to dynamically select values from table in pentaho?

Tags: sql, pentaho-data-integration

I want to execute a query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER 
WHERE ID = ${id}
```

in Pentaho.

I have a previous step - 'Modified JavaScript value' where I get multiple values of 'id' as variable, but its not working when I try to use that value in 'Table Input' step.

Please help me find the correct steps.

Comment: I don't know the answer but that looks like SQL injection which you should avoid. Use parameterized queries instead.